# Pass XML as input parameter in WS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, wcf

A have a web method with input parameter type of string. But this parameter actually is not string but xml. The example of input is:

```
<![CDATA[<check>
  <id>12354564</id>
  <idMeaning>msisdn</idMeaning>
<amount>500</amount>
</check>]]>
```

Bellow is snipped form my code where i create the input and call the method

```
// create xml
var xml = new XElement("check",             
                new XElement("id", "41504823"), 
                new XElement("idMeaning", "msisdn"),
                new XElement("amount", "500")
                );      

// add CDATA
var input = new XCData(xml.ToString());

// get client
var client = WSWrapper.GetClient();

// call method
client.DoCheck(input.ToString());
```

But then I have problems with encoding. If I check request over the wire I can see that xml has been encoded like

```
 &lt;![CDATA[&lt;check&gt;
 &lt;id&gt;41504823&lt;/id&gt;
 &lt;idMeaning&gt;msisdn&lt;/idMeaning&gt;
 &lt;amount&gt;500&lt;/amount&gt;
 &lt;/check&gt;]]&gt
```

How can I prevent this encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you are reading it over the wire you are not reading it in XML format, that's in text format which "lt" stands for "less than", "<" and gt, "greater than", ">".

Be sure that you  have the declaration at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```